# Is pushing a ZFS NAS Backup to a Tape Backup for long-term family archiving efficient?

Tags: backup, zfs, tape

**It's quite expensive to move to tape, so for my setup, would it be efficient?**  Im looking for suggestions for efficiency towards either just building up my existing backup (`NAS`), and documenting it for ease of use for others(succeeding family/users/great-great-grandchildren,etc..), or combining that with adding a tape backup too, which others could just eventually replace out the `NAS` completely with a family accessible Tape, thereby eliminating the complexity(when it's time to retire).

The setup is;
Data source:
The data source is a daily Win10 home family/file-share pc which contains 2 large extra drives, one is a User only drive containing only user specific files, and the other is a public file share music/video/game/etc.
Server:
The backup server is a `Linux` `NAS` using `ZFS` Raidz2, smb/nfs accessible, with snapshots and `RO` file shares.

Files are pushed to the server via the Win10 box using `freefilesync`(ffs)(its awesome).

It feels as if the NAS is still fairly vulnerable, being all in one box, one location, aging drives, etc.. If a drive fails it can take a week to `resilver` large data sets which if you get another failure during that time your redundancy is gone.  This makes me nervous.  I think after moving it to a RaidZ3 with a hot spare always online will help me rest at ease though.

A a problem could still exist for any other single point of failure of the linux box as well, bringing things offline, but at least just temporary.  Still, one fire, or theft, and the data is gone.

Ideally we can get rid of these vulnerabilities.  They cause me to lose concentration in moments of need, and to be a bit haphazard when backing up data in a rush upon the 'single-point-of-failure emergencies`'

Im now thinking of something to ask the community about:  I believe that tape is still king, after reading up here on server fault.  Q: **So what if `NAS` was backed with a TAPE on some periodic schedule, or loop?** http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspxItem=N82E16840108119

**If backed up on tape, will the NAS still even be needed?**  I'm thinking of leaving it in tact, as my normal backup system, and incorporating tape along with it.  Essentially this would be using the `NAS` as the primary backup point, then backing this up 4 times annually to Tape.  **Alternatively, does one suggest to just scrap the `NAS`, and replace it with tape?**  Seems it would be a lot of wasted tape that way.  Also maybe thats not the best question, because personally this `NAS` is also used as a RO file share, so it is still used where a Tape couldn't be.

**Now, if you have an opinion, would it change things knowing that the `NAS` was built on the highly superior `ZFS` file-system?  What if it was a RAIDZ2 setup?**

scenario 1) No redundancy, we have a single bus-bar failure, and the backup is offline, now when the Win drive kicks off, data loss occurs in the downtime of the bus bar possibly..  However, the tape backup didn't run anyway. **Or should that be left looping on a normal basis and shut off at a point of failure?**

scenario 2) With redundancy, a drive kicks off, no problem..

**So suggestions here on a proper fail-safe backup policy?**  This is for PRICELESS family pictures/documents/genealogy etc.., and should lead to easier maintenance for my wife/extended family once I "KICK" off ideally.

Answer (score 3):

ZFS is not a replacement for a good backup.
That being stated ZFS is awesome and to me dual disk ZFS in either raidz2 or better yet a stripe of mirrored vdevs, provided you had another copy (preferably another ZFS box) on another machine, preferably offsite would be sufficient.
Tape does have its place as well and super long term is definitely among them and is something that your wife can easily send somewhere and have a copy made if the situation of you kicking came up pretty easily.

Maybe cloud might become an option provided the size of your PRICELESS pictures underpaces per GB disk price.

Comment: sorry, cracking up on your response of me "kicking off", love it.  Straight to the point, and appreciated.  Just funny!  But tape will be much easier for her wouldnt it?  I mean, if she just had to unplug some e-sata or digital connector over form linux box to whatever win PC she would be using at the time, and has somebody keep it configured, and the files moved to a new useful location?  Or should i focus on no tape then, and document ZFS for dummies, and encourage use of always Keeping the backup functioning? Or just buy Crash Plan before she offlines the ZFS..

Comment: and yes cloud is the obvious offline area, pointing to Crash Plan.  Maybe that would be the wiser choice, teach her how to keep data backed up to cloud, and myself use ZFS, and enact an immediate cloud policy/then breakdown of SAN shoud l kick off.  Hows that one?

Comment: Well its really a matter of what you feel like is adequate protection. I mean it is not like money can replace this stuff. If budget allowed. the best thing would be to have a tape backup and have the online as the online would be easiest for everyone to deal with and if your house burned and the online service somehow failed you would still have the tape (provided it was offsite). :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't the forget the non-zero risk of fire, theft, natural disasters, etc.
Take a serious look at cloud backup services.  There's a number of them that offer unlimited backup space (be sure to read the fine print to understand exactly what "unlimited" means though) for under $100 **per year**.

Compared to $2400 for a tape unit plus media, this could be an attractive option.

Edit: Look for something with continuous backup protection if you're concerned about "doing backups".

Comment: Crash plan!! Yeah, thanks for reminding me of fire, although i think of it all the time related to data backup, i didnt seem to correlate it this time around.  Great point!  So Cloud looks like it might play a part as a backup for the ZFS, or the primary data set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the days of tape have gone for this application. Tapes degrade over time, formats change, hardware fails, etc. If the data is that valuable then you should be prepared to back it up to something that has a greater chance of being around some time into the future.

Personally, I use Crashplan to backup my home ZFS-based NAS. The family unlimited plan works for me and all the devices in my house. There's something in the order of 1.8TB of data in the cloud. It took ages to make the initial backup, but the rate of change is not too great.

I also have a FreeNAS device down in my home office at the bottom of the garden that mirrors the NAS. That allows me to do a fast local restore if necessary.

As to the issue of what happens if you peg it: my wife's PC also uses Crashplan and I've written out detailed instructions on how to access everything.

OT: Incidentally, I've done this by creating a shared Evernote notebook that has a load of similar Emergency stuff in it. No passwords however; they are all stored in LastPass but my wife knows where I put a file card with my master password on it.

Comment: I don't have much experience with consumer-based backup providers, but most of the serious commercial based providers will allow you to create a seed drive (basically the initial backup, encrypted) on an external USB drive and ship it to them to ease the burden of the initial backup.  I'm assuming this is probably an optional service available with some of the consumer services (possibly for a fee?)